# Bloc builder does not update list view builder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a list of Objects in my bloc's state and i pass it to a List view like that

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(builder: (_, settingsState) { 
              ...
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                      
                          itemCount: settingsState.ActiveSettings.length,
                          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                            return Visibility(
                            visible: settingsState.ActiveSettings[index].Visible,
                            child: SettingCard(settingsState.ActiveSettings[index], SettLogic));
                          }
                        )
              )
              ...
}
}
```

Setting State is like this:

```
class SettingsState{
  late bool UnsavedSettings;
  late bool UnsavedUserGroups;
  late String SelectedGroupName;
  List<GroupSetting> ActiveSettings = new List.empty(growable: true);
  SettingsState(bool unsavedSettings,bool unsavedUsergroups,String selectedGroupName, List<GroupSetting> activeSettings){
    UnsavedSettings = unsavedSettings;
    UnsavedUserGroups = unsavedUsergroups;
    SelectedGroupName = selectedGroupName;
    ActiveSettings = new List.from(activeSettings);
  }
}
```

The code that is executed to emit the new State is:

```
List<GroupSetting> ActiveSettings = GetSettings(event.Setting.GroupName);
SettingsState newState = new SettingsState(SettingChanges.values.length != 0,UserGroupChanges.values.length != 0,event.Setting.GroupName,ActiveSettings);
yield newState;
```

*Bloc Builder is initialized in this widget

But List did not refresh(I am new to flutter but i have a similar example for other data and works)

**UPDATE: As i am looking to solve this error i found out that list get the state and if i scroll up and down i get the updated widget from state but it doesn't refresh it automatically

Any thoughts?

Comment: please, share your more code for better understanding

Comment: @Poran i added my state object too.

Comment: I don't see any BlocBuilder or even a command to change the state of a BloC. If you want us to help with your code, you have to actually *post* that code here.

Comment: is called block builder when you try to refresh your list?

Comment: i thought you understood where the object came from from its name. I made an update so you can see better the flow of my code